# Spring Boot @ManagedResource component is not visible in VisualVM when launched in Docker but works locally

Tags: java, docker, jmx, spring-jmx

The issue is very straightforward to reproduce. I have a Spring component:

```java
@Component
@ManagedResource
public class EncryptionUtil {

   ...

    @ManagedOperation
    public String encrypt(String plain) {
       ...
    }

    @ManagedOperation
    public String decrypt(String encrypted) {
       ...
    }
}
```

When I launch the app locally (using IDE) and connecting over JMX using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io) I can see and manage the bean:
[image]

But, when I launch the app in a container (locally as well), I do not see the bean. Moreover, I do not see any Spring related managing facilities as well:

[image]

Here is my JMX opts that I pass into Dockerfile entrypoint when launchign the JAR file within:

```sh
JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true\
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false\
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false\
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false\
          -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$DOCKER_HOST_IP\
          -Dserver.port=$PORT\
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090\
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9090"
```

`DOCKER_HOST_IP=127.0.0.1` when launch locally obviously.

So issue, that MBeans are not recognized in a container at all.

Any idea folks?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out that the solution is very simple: add to your JMX_OPT the following property:

`-Dspring.jmx.enabled=true`

details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M2/reference/html/production-ready-jmx.html)